# HP 14-v015TU notebook touchpad is detected as PS2 mouse with any Ubuntu

Tags: touchpad, hp

I bought a new HP Laptop. Its touch pad is working fine with Windows but detected as a PS2 mouse with any Ubuntu version (14.04, 14.10, 12.04). I updated each time I installed.

Some suggest using "synaptiks" but that prompted `no touch device found`.

I reset BIOS by removing the CMOS battery and then pressing and holding power button for 10 seconds, but that did not help.

My BIOS Version was Insyde F.09 now updated to F.35 I think.

How can I fix this?

The result from

```
xinput list 
⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)] 
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)] 
⎜ ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse id=11 [slave pointer (2)] 
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master k..
```

Comment: I have the same problema with my HP 14-v066br. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Someone reported this BUG on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1408893

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by upgrading to the 4.1 kernel:

Install latest kernel 4.1 from [this page on Ubuntu Portal](http://ubuntuportal.com/2015/08/kernel-4-1-6-lts-ubuntu.html)

**Reboot**

Now you will find new touchpad settings in mouse settings.

If wireless does not work [Download latest bcmwl Broadcom wireless Firmware(If it apply to you)](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu3/+build/7418309) which is the correct driver for this device

Download the `.deb` file, open Terminal, `cd` to the directory where it went (probably `Downloads`), and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```